# Error en resultado de Case en SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, condiciones, sql-server-management

Bueno quisiera reabrir la pregunta de nuevo, ya que anteriormente corregi como me indicaron y todo bien hasta que le agregue mas filtros y este ya no me trajo de nuevo los resultados que proporcione segun los filtros, esta es mi consulta:

```
SELECT nombre, puesto, municipio,
case when (puesto='operador' puesto='repartidor' or puesto='cajero' or puesto='transportista' or puesto='ensamblador') and 
(idjefe=945281 or idjefe=870024) and
(idjefe!=923321 or idjefe!=564322) and
DATEDIFF(DAY,A.hireDate,GETDATE()) > 14 then 'Entrenador de empleados'
when (puesto='repartidor' or puesto='cajero' or puesto='transportista'  or puesto='ensamblador') then 'Empleado Regular' 
end as 'Classification 2',
idjefe
from Empleados
```

Y bueno la parte en la que tengo error es cuando especifico que los idjefe (923321 & 564322) hagan una excepcion y no los tome en cuenta aunque cumplan con la condicion y no les ponga 'Entrenador de empleados' y este tenga 'Empleado Regular' y con mi consulta aun asi estos idjefe tienen 'Entrenador de empleados'... como puedo acomodar esta consulta para que respete esa condicion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola esto pasa porque se cumple la primera condicion y ya no pasa a la segunda lo que puedes hacer es mover los ifs, el que tienes en la segunda posicion cambiarlo a la primera. Algo asi (cambie un poco la sintaxis)

```
SELECT nombre, puesto, municipio,
case when (puesto='operador' puesto='repartidor' or puesto='cajero' or puesto='transportista' or puesto='ensamblador') and idjefe in (945281,870024) then 'Entrenador de empleados'
when (puesto='repartidor' or puesto='cajero' or puesto='transportista'  or puesto='ensamblador') then 'Empleado Regular' 
end as 'Classification 2',
idjefe
from Empleados
```

Comment: Tuviste toda la razon, nose porque nunca se me paso por la cabeza :x